# Step-down Lipo voltage to 1.9v

Tags: arduino, atmega328p, step-down

I'm trying to power a MMA9995l, NRF24l01, HDC2080 and ATMEGA328P from a Lipo battery. The perfect voltage for this is 1.9V. Since I'm quite new to component sourcing and step-down converters in general, I'm not having the best of luck finding a suitable step-down dc-dc converter. Currently I'm looking at the TPS6273x since it has a Max rating of 4.2V and that is the top of my lipo voltage range. Does anyone have an alternative with a lower Iq, since this one is 25 uA, which is 5 times the usage of my total system in sleep mode. Does anyone have tips for designing low voltage circuits? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Go to www.ti.com, they have lots of dc-dc converters to choose from.

Comment: Consider a hybrid strategy... the 328P is powered by an LDO. It then turns on the DC-DC converter only when needed, saving the Iq only when needed. Or there's some other supervisory circuit which turns things on only when needed as described [in this article](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21802213/designing-ultralowpower-sensor-nodes-for-iot-applications).

Comment: Thanks ErikR! I hadn't thought of this! I will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're searching for a DC-DC converter, there are a few questions to ask first:

1. What are your maximum and minimum input voltages? (In this case, presumably 4.2V and ~3V, from a LiPo battery.)
2. What is your output voltage?  Is it lower than your minimum input voltage? (Buck converter)  Is it higher than your maximum input voltage? (Boost converter)  Is it in between? (Buck-Boost)  Is it negative? (inverting)
3. What current do you need?
4. How integrated do you need/want? (Integrated switches?  Integrated switches and inductor? More integrated is usually more expensive, more efficient, less flexible, lower max power)

Once you have answers to these questions, you can search on a manufacturer website or a distributor website to find a part that fits your needs.

In this case, here's what I found with a quick search on TI's website:  In the section Home / Power management / DC/DC switching regulators / Step-down (buck) regulators / Buck converters (integrated switch), there are 7 parts with Iq < 1 uA that meet your voltage requirements and have a maximum current more than 100mA.  [This is a link to the search I did](https://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/step-down-buck/buck-converter-integrated-switch/products.html#p238min=1.5;4.2&p238max=4.2;7&p634min=-3;1.9&p634max=1.9;90&p451max=0.1;0.5&p386typ=0.06;1.5&p212max=53.06122448979591;100).  It looks like the TPS62742 would be a good choice for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was very helpfull! Unfortunatly, none of them are in stock with my usual stores (lcsc, mouser, farnell). Are there any other good dc-dc converter manufacturers.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I find LCSC's search nigh-unusable.  In this case, your key characteristic is quiescent current, which isn't a search filter on their search.  If you want to try to search manually for a low-quiescent-current buck converter on their website they have thousands of buck converters and at least a hundred that can do LiPo to 1.9V.  For better or for worse, DC-DC converters are a big market and the big IC manufacturers (TI, Analog Devices, Renesas, Diodes Incorporated) are all in it.